# How to go back to normal YouTube homepage?

Tags: youtube

Now when I go to youtube.com it only shows me the videos that I watched before or something similar. I have to **log out** my Google account to get the normal home page and see the videos that are actually new and interesting, or at least get these buttons.

[image: screen shot]

But then I was logged out for all my Google apps such as Gmail, Calendar. This is really annoying. Now I basically have to use a separate browser to watch YouTube, but then I can't save or comment. Is there a way I can get back the normal non-personalized home page even when I'm logged in?

Comment: You can use the Google Chrome's Incognito browser mode so that you can see popular videos without having to log out every single time.

Answer (score 1):

When signed out go to the "Browse Channel's" at the bottom, there will be some tiles. The first one should be "Popular on Youtube." Underneath that will be a subscribe button. Click it, sign in, and when you want to go there, just click it in the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

If you click the "Browse Channels" button on the sidebar, you can access them.

Comment: That is true. But even then, if I go to say _popular on youtube_, there're still a large chunk of videos that're _recommended_. And I still don't have those buttons on the left.